# Checking if checkbox is checked in MVC 4 without a submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a checkbox:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <label>
        Archived
        @Html.CheckBox("checkedArchive")
    </label>
</form>
```

When it's checked, I want it to call the ContentResult which has a number of methods in place with an additional new value to check whether it was checked/unchecked:

```
public ContentResult Data(int? id)
```

So far, I have:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formData)
{
    bool checked;

    //Check if value is selected and set bool to true or false

    return RedirectToAction("Data", new {checked});
}
```

But I'm unable to do any checking and passing. There must be a simpler way.

Comment: You can also use an `Ajax` function linked to your checkbox. So when It is checked you use the appropriate event to wrap your the action you will call

Comment: Should I post another question as I'm new to MVC and I don't particularly understand?

Comment: Have a look on my update.

Comment: Thanks Inankian. Apologies for not being clearer. I just simply wish to check if the checkbox was checked as opposed to firing an event on checked. Please see my updated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215949/posting-results-when-checkbox-is-checked-in-mvc-4

Answer (score 1):

bool checked=Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(c => c.Contains("checkedArchive")).FirstOrDefault() != null;

Since only the checked values will be posted back you don't need to validate that they're checked.

Comment: Thats not correct - also not checked values are posted to the server!

Comment: Have you posted the view on Action Index  by using any mean?

Answer (score 0):

I check for generic checkboxes the following way:

```
bool checked = Request.Form["checkedArchive"] != "false";
```

Comment: Hi, this doesn't work nor would it poll for whether the box was checked or not.

Comment: Yes it does - I use this all over my app! Of course you need to post the data somehow to the server otherwise it can't work...

Comment: I've put this inside a method and it always returns true regardless of whether it's checked or not. How I automatically get it to reload the data if the box was checked?

Comment: You mean how you post the data to the server? That works via a form post/submit and there are several ways to do this. Please explain your use case in more detail...

Comment: I do. In short; data is posted on a calendar. When the archived button is selected, the data is updated with new parameters. There are no forms or submit buttons. Think .NET equivalent to OnClick or OnEvent. I want the event to fire with updated results as soon as the checkbox is checked. Then for that check to be inside of ContentResult Data.

Comment: Ok, for that you need JavaScript and trigger an AJAX form post on the change event of the checkbox and is outside of the scope of this question IMO. Maybe create a new question better specified to that topic or simply search for it - there is enough information about this stuff around...

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to change the signature of your index like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formData, bool? checkedArchive)
{
    bool checked;
    if(!checkedArchive.HasValue) 
        checked = false;
    else
        checked = checkedArchive.Value;

    //Check if value is selected and set bool to true or false

    return RedirectToAction("Data", new {checked});
}
```

I hope it will help. Note that this solution will work if you have a `submit button`. What you trying to achieve I think you need to use a `Jquery Ajax function attached to the event change of your`checkbox` and call the appropriate action in your controller.

### Update

First you need to reference the JQuery lib in your view and then put this script in the head in the head

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#HcheckedArchiven").click(function(){
     $.ajax({

        url: '@Url.Action("actionmethod", "controllername")',
        type: "POST",
        data: //data,
        dataType: //type of response,
        success: function (data) {
          //your code here
         }
   error: function(data){

       }
   });});
 })
```

Also that if you want to call ajax not on click but only if value is checked or not then you must use an if condition in the click event to check the same using $(this).is(:checked)

Comment: This is a very easy solution if you only have this one value and a "hardcoded" name - Jayesh and my solution are more generic...

Comment: But he said it doesn't work. I just proposed an easy solution as the generic solution doesn't work. Will have a another view on yours.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant for you or the OP - it was more a general statement for others finding this so they do not get the idea they are required to add a parameter for every value...

Comment: @Inanikian - Can I check in public ContentResult Data(int? id) If the box has been checked? FormCollection doesn't bring anything back.

Comment: @darkshadoway you can update then your `ContentResult` signature method and the post link also. Know that there are many solutions so you must try one and then people can help you from that.

Answer (score 0):

Without submitting the form, you can make the ajax request and send the checkbox's values as parameter.
After sending this value to the controller you can determine the value in the parameter, And call your required method against the value.