# Posting results when checkbox is checked in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been asked to repost this question with more detail.

I'm new to MVC and I'd appreciate any supporting explanations although I am quite grounded in .NET development.

**Scenario**

I have a calendar that posts to a calendar with information when it's selected. It looks like this:

```
@foreach (var OfflineCalendar in Model.OfflineCalendars.Skip(1))
{
    <li data-name="@OfflineCalendar.Name" data-val="@OfflineCalendar.Id">@Html.ActionLink(OfflineCalendar.Name, "Index", new { Id = OfflineCalendar.Id }, new { @class = "location" })</li>
 }
```

The calendar only returns data for a month which passes some data to a ContentResult method.

I've added a Checkbox for archived data.

```
<label>
    Archived
    @Html.CheckBox("checkedArchive")
</label>
```

**My Task**

I want to add an archived button where a user can view historic data. If this checkbox is checked, it changes some parameters in the ContentResult Data method.

**The Dilemma**

In .NET I would easily check for whether a checkbox is checked and fire an event based on the calendar that's selected. I'm struggling to do the MVC equivalent.

All I want to do is check if it's checked WHEN a calendar location is selected. If it is, return a bool of true or false. Which will affect the ContentResult.

I don't want to use Ajax. I just simply want to check whether a checkbox is checked when a location is selected. That's all.

Here's the related question I asked: [***clicky***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214586/checking-if-checkbox-is-checked-in-mvc-4-without-a-submit-button?noredirect=1#comment35514265_23214586)

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You can it check it by javascript

Comment: I just wish to check if it was checked and pass it code side.

Comment: make sure that your checkbox must be within "form" tag.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to do all of this server side through your existing code and just want to access the value of the checkbox.

If that is correct, I would modify the ViewModel to include a boolean "IncludeArchived" and then add it to your page:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IncludeArchived)
```

When you submit your form the value should be included in your Model.

Alternatively, you could check Request.Form["checkedArchive"] on the server side and parse that into a boolean.

Comment: You're right on the ball. When I do string checkedBox = Request.Form["checkedArchive"]; it returns null regardless of whether it's checked or not. Any ideas? I opted for the second as I don't properly understand the first method.

Comment: If I remember rightly, you can give the checkbox a value="1". If it is checked, then Request.Form["checkedArchive"] will give "1", if it isn't then you will get null.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write checkbox event in jquery and check if checkbox is checked post the form and return content from server else don't post the form.

Like this:

View:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="MyForm">
    <label>
        Archived
        @Html.CheckBox("checkedArchive")
    </label>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#checkedArchive').on('change',function(){


if(this.checked)
{

$('#MyForm').submit();

}


});
```

Comment: Salaam, I just wish to check if the checkbox was checked as opposed to submit on checked.

Comment: you can see that if the if condition is true it acknowlwdges that checkbox is check do whatever you want to on the case of checked